# After upgrading from laravel 5.4 to 5.5 HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: nginx, laravel-5.5, php-7.2

```
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "MatthiasMullie/Minify": "^1.3",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "kbsali/redmine-api": "^1.5",
        "kordy/ticketit": "^0.3.6",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "1.*",
        "milon/barcode": "^5.0",
        "psr/http-message": "^1.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "jamesiarmes/php-ntlm": "dev-master",
        "php-ews/php-ews": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Logs say what the 500 error is?

Comment: Every time you get a 500 internal server error just go into the logs and see what's wrong.
In this case also follow the laravel upgrade steps (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0). And ... Laravel 5.5 is PHP7 only, so triple-check that you have PHP 7 installed on your server.

Please tell the exact steps you did before you got this error. Your composer.json looks like laravel 5.4 and not laravel 5.5, so you haven't completed the upgrade steps